# Finding id's not in other table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Help!

I am trying to find the customer that are in VBSTEST that are not in VMFG9. the tables have identical schema. Whenever i run the query i never get a result returning.

```
`SELECT [ROWID]
      ,[ID]
      ,[NAME]
      ,[ADDR_1]
      ,[ADDR_2]
      ,[ADDR_3]
      ,[CITY]
      ,[STATE]
      ,[ZIPCODE]
      ,[COUNTRY]
  FROM [VMFG9].[dbo].[CUSTOMER] 
   where NOT EXISTS(
        select v6.[ID]
        from [VBSTEST].[dbo].[CUSTOMER] as v6
        left outer join [VMFG9].[dbo.CUSTOMER] as v9 on  v9.id = v6.[id]
        where v9.id is null);`
```

Comment: Is there any wrong in your question ? If you want to find customers that are in VBSTEST and not in VMFG9, your query cannot Select * from VMFG9

Answer (score 1):

The subquery that you want doesn't use a `join`:

```
select . . .
from [VMFG9].[dbo].[CUSTOMER] c
where not exists (select 1
                  from [VBSTEST].[dbo].[CUSTOMER] v6
                  where c.id = v6.id
                 );
```

You can use `left join`/`where` in the *outer* query, if you prefer.  But a single table reference is sufficient for the `not exists`.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do this is:

```
select id from [VBSTEST].[dbo].[CUSTOMER]
except
select id from [VMFG9].[dbo].[CUSTOMER];
```

You should also find that this kind of query is faster too.

Apart from being much longer, I think that there is an error in your query.  Since null never equals anything else, it doesn't even equal null, then your condition:

```
where v9.id is null
```

means that the condition

```
v9.id = v6.[id]
```

can never be true.

Answer (score 0):

With your `NOT EXISTS` you are currently saying, select all rows only when the subquery returns no results (else return nothing).

The subquery itself should be adequate:

```
select v6.*
from [VBSTEST].[dbo].[CUSTOMER] as v6
left outer join [VMFG9].[dbo.CUSTOMER] as v9 on  v9.id = v6.[id]
where v9.id is null
```